# Parameter sets not mandatory

Tags: powershell

Two parameters $installDatabase and $databasePassword:

```
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Test', mandatory=$false)][Switch]$installDatabase,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Test')][String]$databasePassword
```

I need this to perform the same functionality as this if:

```
if ($installDatabase -and !($databasePassword) -or ($databasePassword -and !($installDatabase)))
{ 
Write-Verbose "Use -installDatabase and -databasePassword together."
}
```

What is wrong with the ParameterSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: OK here is a version where the parameter set is evaluated

```
function test
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Test")]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Test', mandatory=$true)]
        [switch]$installDatabase,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Test2', mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$databasePassword
    )
}
```

In this version either you call `test -installDatabase` or `test -databasePassword pwd` 
or the following exception occurs:

```
test : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
```

Comment: The issue is the if statement is outside the param block. I need a solution where an exception is thrown if the parameters are not passed together. Parameter sets might not not provide this.

Comment: OK, it wasn't clear from the question, here is an update

Answer (score 1):

```
function Do-Something{    
    Param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Test', Mandatory=$true)]
        [Switch]$installDatabase,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Test', Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$databasePassword
    )
}
```

`]` was missing before `[String]`

Comment: Apologies - that was a typo. The functionality still does not work.

Comment: I need the ParameterSet to evaluate the same condition as the if statement shown. Is this possible? So, an exception is thrown if the two parameters are not used in conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

(tested on PS v5)

It appears that parameter sets only work when at least two are defined - however, rather than raising an exception the user is prompted to supply the missing values (because of `Mandatory=$True`), which might not be what you want.

If the `Param` definition is changed to:

```
Param(
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Test1', Mandatory=$True)]
[Switch]$installDatabase,

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Test1', Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$databasePassword,

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Test2')]
[String]$something
)
```

The user is prompted for `installDatabase` or `databasePassword` if only one of them is supplied, and not prompted if `something` is supplied.

An exception is raised if `something` and (`installDatabase` or `databasePassword`) is supplied.

If only one parameter set is defined, it's as if none is.

**EDIT**

Attempting to use a default value of `($throw...)` for the optional parameters, like:

```
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Test1')]
[Switch]$installDatabase=$(throw "installDatabase is mandatory if databasePassword is provided"),
```

doesn't work, because the default value is used whether or not the parameter set is applicable.